# Does using a Virtual Wifi Miniport Adapter decreases the performance of my Wifi card?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, performance, adapter, hotspot

I have this theory, my wifi signal in Windows 7 is very poor, I tested in Ubuntu and it gets a really good signal.

In Windows I use a Virtual wifi miniport adapter to make a wifi hotspot. I read somewhere that doing this the overall power of the wifi card is divided by the 2 connections.

It is possible that I'm getting a crappy connection to my router because of this?
If so, do you know how to disable it? Because although I can disable the Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport Adapter, I have no idea of how uninstall it. I read it comes with the drivers?

Also the wifi card is an Atheros AR5007G and is a PCI in a desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using virtual wifi shouldn't affect the strength of your signal. It looks to me like your driver isn't very good on Windows but it is good on Linux.

You really can't uninstall that adapter once you've turned on hosted network. It shouldn't matter though so don't sweat it.